# Cardinal of the set of subfields of the reals.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, field-theory

What is the cardinal number $|G|$ of the set $G$  of all subfields of $R$, the real numbers? For $S\subset R$ let $Q[S]$ be the subfield generated by $S$, which is the smallest field $F\subset R$ such that $S\subset F$.It is obvious that $|Q[S]|=|S|+\omega$, and easy to show that if $k$ is an infinite cardinal with $k<|R|$ then $|G|\geq k^+$ . (Where $k^+$ is the least cardinal greater than $k$).It follows that $|G|\geq |R|$ but intuitively I suspect $|G|=2^{|R|}$.I don't know how to do more.NOTE.I am assuming the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: Consider sets of algebraically independent transcendentals.

Comment: This certainly is something I've considered but I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand, every subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ *is* a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (with some properties), so we have the upper bound $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ for the cardinality of $G$, where $\mathfrak{c} = \operatorname{card} \mathbb{R} = 2^{\aleph_0}$.

On the other hand, let $\mathcal{B}$ be a [transcendence basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_basis) of the field extension $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$. Then $\operatorname{card} \mathcal{B} = \mathfrak{c}$, so $\mathcal{B}$ has $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ distinct subsets. Since $\mathcal{B}$ is algebraically independent, distinct subsets $S_1,S_2$ of $\mathcal{B}$ generate different subfields $\mathbb{Q}(S_1) \neq \mathbb{Q}(S_2)$ of $\mathbb{R}$, so we also have $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ as a lower bound of $\operatorname{card} G$.